# Disposed JFrame messing up infinite while loop

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jframe, swingworker

So I have a program which intakes a few values through a Scanner and then changes a `BufferedImage` on a `JFrame` accordingly. The way it changes the frame continues indefinitely through an infinite while loop. This works quickly (clearing the entire 1920x1080 frame in a few seconds) and works fine without `SwingWorker` or `InvokeLater` or anything.

To update the program away from a Scanner, I decided to make another frame to input variables before the main program begins. The new frame takes the values, and once a `JButton` is clicked, disposes of itself and sends the values to the main program.

The problem is, once these variables were passed to the main program, the main frame in that program would create itself but freeze, and be completely transparent. This originally caught me off guard, as I could see my Eclipse window but couldn't click anything since the frame was in the way, covering the whole screen.

I tried and succeeded at using `SwingWorker` and `InvokeLater`, but the time either of them took to cover the frame changed from a few seconds to around thirty minutes (I calculated, didn't actually wait that long). I'm not sure why I can't use a frame to get the variables instead of a Scanner, since either way the variables get passed to the main program, and the previous frame is disposed of. I'm not too familiar with the EDT or Swing Event Queue, so any help is appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Colors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Color Choice (Red/Green/Blue)");
            String colorInput = scanner.nextLine();

            Color changingColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            if (colorInput.equals("Red"))
                changingColor = Color.RED;
            else if (colorInput.equals("Green"))
                changingColor = Color.GREEN;
            else if (colorInput.equals("Blue"))
                changingColor = Color.BLUE;

            scanner.close();
            changing(changingColor);
         */

        //OR

        /*
            JFrame frame = newJFrame("Start // Menu");
    
            String[] colors = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
            JSpinner colorSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerListModel(colors));
            colorSpinner.setBounds(frame.getWidth()/2 - 40, frame.getHeight()/3 - 20, 80, 40);
            frame.add(colorSpinner);
    
            JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
            okButton.setBounds(frame.getWidth()/2 - 40, frame.getHeight()/2 - 20, 80, 40);
            okButton.addActionListener(event -> {
                Color changingColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);
                if (colorSpinner.getValue().equals("Red"))
                    changingColor = Color.RED;
                else if (colorSpinner.getValue().equals("Green"))
                    changingColor = Color.GREEN;
                else if (colorSpinner.getValue().equals("Blue"))
                    changingColor = Color.BLUE;
    
                frame.dispose();
    
                changing(changingColor);
            });
            frame.add(okButton);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        */
    }

    public static JFrame newJFrame(String title) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        return frame;
    }

    public static void changing(Color changingColor) {
        Color color = changingColor;

        JFrame frame = newJFrame("Color Changer // Main");

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        JLabel imageL = new JLabel();
        imageL.setBounds(frame.getBounds());
        imageL.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        frame.add(imageL);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        int x = 0, y = 0;
        while (true) {
            image.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());

            imageL.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            frame.repaint();

            x++;
            if (x >= frame.getWidth()) {
                x = 0;
                y++;
                if (y >= frame.getHeight()) {
                    y = 0;

                    if (color.equals(Color.RED)) {
                        color = Color.GREEN;
                    } else if (color.equals(Color.GREEN)) {
                        color = Color.BLUE;
                    } else if (color.equals(Color.BLUE)) {
                        color = Color.RED;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I'm not too familiar with the EDT or Swing Event Queue, so any help is appreciated* - Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). All updates to Swing components should be made on the EDT. If you want looping code then use a `SwingWorker` and "publish" results. Or use a Swing Timer for animation. The tutorial also has a section on "How to Use Swing Timers". Don't use a Scanner to get user input. Use a JOptionPane or a custom JDialog to get user input before starting your processing.

Comment: Note that using a SwingWorker should not cause any noticeable slowdown for that sort of task, however, for a SwingWorker to function correctly the `while` loop needs to be inside the SwingWorker, was that the case in your code? If so, please edit your question to show what you tried with the swing worker.

Comment: Tip: Add @sorifiend (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SwingWorker publishing the works of an infinite while loop in doInBackground() works great. For some reason earlier when I had tried a SwingWorker I ran it once and then ran it again once it finished. Again pretty new to Swing concurrency and SwingWorkers, obviously. Big thanks to @camickr and @sorifiend!!

Answer (score 1):

The following code is an mre of a `JFrame` with repeatedly changing background color.
The main changes implemented are:

1. Removed loop from edt. Used a Swing `Timer` to control animation
2. Did all custom painting on a `JPanel` rather than a `JFrame`
3. Changed background color without using a `BufferedImage` (Using  BufferedImage is possible but not needed).
4. Used `JOptionPane` to get user's input rather than a `JFrame`

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.*;
    
    public class Colors {
    
        public static final int CLI = 0, GUI = 1;
        private Color color = Color.RED;//default value
        private static final int CYCLE_TIME = 1000;
        private static final String[] colorsNames = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
    
        public Colors(int userInputBy) {
    
            if(userInputBy == CLI){
                cliInput();
            }else if (userInputBy == GUI){
                guiInput();
            }//or else use default
    
            changing();
        }
    
        private void guiInput() {
    
            //use JOptionPane to get input from user 
            JSpinner colorSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerListModel(colorsNames));
            int answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, colorSpinner, "Select color", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            String colorName ="";
            if (answer == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {// user selected a color
                colorName = (String) colorSpinner.getValue();
            }
    
            colorByName(colorName);
        }
    
        private void cliInput() {
    
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Color Choice (Red/Green/Blue)");
            String colorName = scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.close();
            colorByName(colorName);
        }
    
        private void colorByName(String colorName) {
    
            if (colorName.equals(colorsNames[0])) {
                color = Color.RED;
            } else if (colorName.equals(colorsNames[1])) {
                color = Color.GREEN;
            } else if (colorName.equals(colorsNames[2])) {
                color = Color.BLUE;
            }
        }
    
        private void changing() {
    
            JFrame frame = newJFrame("Color Changer // Main");
            ChangingColorPane ccp = new ChangingColorPane(color);
            frame.add(ccp);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            //use swing time to animate
            Timer timer = new Timer(CYCLE_TIME, e->{
                changeColor();
                ccp.setBgColor(color);
                frame.repaint();
            });
            timer.start();
        }
    
        private void changeColor() {
            if (color.equals(Color.RED)) {
                color = Color.GREEN;
            } else if (color.equals(Color.GREEN)) {
                color = Color.BLUE;
            } else if (color.equals(Color.BLUE)) {
                color = Color.RED;
            }
        }
    
        //do custom painting on a JPanel
        class ChangingColorPane extends JPanel{
    
            private static final int W = 400, H = 500;
            private Color bgColor;
            public ChangingColorPane(Color bgColor) {
                this.bgColor = bgColor;
            }
    
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(bgColor);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
    
            @Override
            public Dimension preferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(W, H);
            }
    
            public void setBgColor(Color bgColor) {
                this.bgColor = bgColor;
            }
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Colors(1);
        }
    
        private static JFrame newJFrame(String title) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            return frame;
        }
    }
```